# Volley 2 problems - ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH not recognized, neither is one of the methods

Tags: android

Trying to import the Volley library for a project that I work on with a colleague, but I get this random error in the middle of one of the Volley files

Here is a screenshot of the situation

[image]

So when I hover over TrafficStats.setThreadStatsTag, I get this error:

```
The method setThreadStatsTag(int) is undefined for the type TrafficStats
```

When I hover over Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH I get this error:

```
ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

What do I do?

I read some related posts about the ICS problem, they all referred to the manufest, But I dont think there is a problem there:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"
    android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the following line in your `project.properties` to 19

```
target=android-19
```

This way you are using the latest version of the SDK, probably you are building against API 12 or lower.

Comment: Thanks Ill give that a go. Right now Im getting "unable to resolve target-19" but when I try to open the SDK manager, it wont start... when I clear this mess up I will tell you what happened :)

Answer (score 0):

Your build target is NOT set to API Level 14 or higher. This is not a bug.
(In eclipse: Project => Properties => Android , and set the target up to API 14 from lower level)